# MySQL database design. New index id

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have an app where there is published content and content under review. I maintain them in separated tables.

Both contents can be voted and commented, when content under review is published I insert it to the published table, BUT votes and comments are not saved, because it’s all separated in different tables.

Tables: published, published_votes, published_comments, reviewing, reviewing_votes, reviewing_comments

I would like to maintain the votes and comments, the problem is that the new post MUST have a new auto increment id, because I show the content ordered by id, otherwise if I order the publications for example by timestamp that makes filesort and it's not an option.

So I will join all tables and have only 3, and when a content is published I can make a new insert on the table or update the id which I think is worse. But **the Problem** is that I would have to update all the votes and comments to the new published id, in some cases there might be thousands of votes, and the update will have to take place at the moment, I guess I could do it asynchronously and delay the publication. But I don't see it as a great solution either.

Any thoughts?

PD: Ideally what I would like is to put the new publication at the end of the table or index without changing the id, and when I select the publications order them by its physic position on the table or index from the bottom regardless of the numerical index value, but obviously that's not possible as far as I know.

Comment: Do you think updating thousands of votes would take a significant amount of time? Usually it doesn't. Also since you need to copy all the data between tables anyway it doesn't need update, just duplication. Which wouldn't happen if you didn't have separate tables, only a flag.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason to keep Unpublished content in separate table?

You can have all content in the same table and respective votes and comments in sub tables. Distinguish the content based on a column 'Type' or 'status' (published / reviewing).

```
Content(Id, Title, Text, Status, ...)
Votes(Id, ContentId, ...)
Comments(Id, ContentId, ...)
```

When a content is newly inserted it's status is 'Reviewing'. Then a content can be published by changing the 'Status' to 'published'. Additionally you can keep a timestamp to save when the status of content was changed to 'published'.

It would need design level changes in your system, but the sooner the better.

Comment: I agree this is the best idea... Additionally I would try to add a DateCreated column instead of sorting on ID, that sounds like it could bite you later (i.e. if you had to do a migration or re-insert some old posts that got lost / corrupted)

Comment: There is already a timestamp, the content was on the same table in the past already, distinguish the two contents in the same table is not a problem. The problem as I explain is that I want a new id because doing order by timestamp is more inefficient. Since it's not unique and not autoincrement it has to order all matched contents, maybe I’m on the wrong and the index will be always ordered and it would be as efficient as ordering by the Primary unique autoincrement key when doing a SELECT?

Comment: Non-clustered indexes are not as fast as primary index, that's true. But having data on same table will save you a lot of trouble of copying related data and transaction management.Table's design should not be dependent on how the data should be ordered. It is a requirement that  can change anytime. Tables should be structured for data integrity and join performance. Indexes should be created for the query performance. If you feel `timestamp` is not enough for your case, you can always add other columns in the order by clause (like id).